# How to run sonarqube on mac?

Tags: java, macos, sonarqube

```
WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported 
major.minor version 52.0
```

I'm trying to run the simplest sonarqube (2 minute intro) project and have gotten this error. From looking around I thought this error was supposed to occur when you don't have the latest version of java installed on mac. I have java version 8, installed via brew, am I missing something?

Comment: Class version 52 corresponds to Java 8, so maybe there's more than one JVM on your system and you're running a different one than you expect. Try typing `java -version` and `which java`, that should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this message when you are trying to run a Java application that requires Java 8, but you only have 7 or lower.

SonarQube requires Java 8 (bytecode version 52.0).
You can try to install Java 8, or try SonarQube 5.5 instead (5.6 was the first version to mandate Java 8).